# Using CRM to manage walking groups

Tags: wordpress, evaluating-civicrm

We are looking for a program to manage walking groups.  These groups may be part of health education, work-place based, or location based (such as a park).  At the very least we want a way for participants to register for a group and receive notification on the event, such as rain cancelations etc. Down the road, we may also want to create profile accounts for participants to track their walking and use it promote competitions. Below is a summary of what we are looking for in a CRM.

- Integrated into existing wordpress website
- Event registration (free and pay capabilities)
- Ability to send out text and email notifications (walking group leader would most likely do this so phone and email information would need to be private)
- Security and privacy of participants (similar to the Remind app)
- Ability to set up social network and log walks into site
- Promote competition with badges/rewards

Would like to know what this application would be able to support from our wishlist above.

Answer (score 3):

With some customization/development, all your wishes can be met by CiviCRM

```
> Integrated into existing wordpress website 
> Event registration (free and pay capabilities)
```

Out of the box functionality. Your WP site server needs to good enough to run CiviCRM though. And events are easy to use (free and paid).

```
> Ability to send out text and email notifications (walking group leader would most likely do this so phone and email information would need to be private)
> Security and privacy of participants (similar to the Remind app)
```

Some customization will be needed.

```
> Ability to set up social network and log walks into site
```

Please elaborate on what you mean by set up social networks. Walks can be events or activities, you will need to figure out what works for you

```
> Promote competition with badges/rewards
```

There are probably a few different ways to do this, may require some development depending on what you need. For example voting on answers like on StackExchange is not available in CiviCRM and will require a reasonable amount of effort.

You should consider working with a CiviCRM [Partner/Contributor](https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors).